# Не отображаются css-стили в админке Django 1.5.2

Tags: django

Только начал разбираться с Django. Так что прошу потерпеть меня. Выполняю все шаги по [Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Во второй части туториала подключается админка. Сделал все, как написано, но моя админка не имеет css-стилей. Читал на stackoverflow кучу вопросов по этой теме, но не смог применить ответы к конкретно моей ситуации.

Расположение моей папки с проектом: `C:\DjangoProjects\blog`.

Что мне надо прописать в `PROJECT_ROOT` и `STATIC_ROOT` и что еще сделать, чтобы оно наконец заработало? Да, `manage.py collectstatic` использовал, `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` в `INSTALLED_APPS` подключен. Второй день не могу ничего сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно оставить `STATIC_ROOT = ''`

`settings.py` должен лежать в корне проекта, тогда:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, u'static'),
)
```

Еще попробуйте скопировать `static` из папки `django` в ваш проект.
Чтобы найти, где у Вас `django`, в консоли сделайте так:

```
python
>>> import django
>>> print django
```